# Exception handling in Spark Scala UDF

Tags: scala, apache-spark, exception, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

```
def parse_values(value: String) = {

      val values = value.split(",").map(_.trim)
      values.foldLeft(Array[(Int, Double)]()) {
        case (acc, present) =>
          val Array(k, v) = present.split(",")(0).split(":")
          acc :+ (k.trim.toInt, v.trim.toDouble)

      }
```

I am currently using the above UDF to parse a column of string into an array of keys and values.
"50:63.25,100:58.38" to [[50,63.2], [100,58.38]].
In some cases, the string is "\N" and I am unable to parse the column value.
If the string is "\N" then I should return an empty array. Can anyone help me to handle this exception or help me adding a new case? I am new to spark-scala.

Error: scala.MatchError: [Ljava.lang.String;@497cb6a9 (of class [Ljava.lang.String;)

Answer (score 0):

You need to check that the resulting Array has two elements. You need a pattern matching like this to avoid that parse error:

```
def parse_values(value: String) = {
    val values = value.split(",").map(_.trim)
    values.foldLeft(Array[(Int, Double)]()) {
      case (acc, present) =>
        val Array(k, v) = {
          present.split(",")(0).split(":") match {
            case Array(_) => Array("0", "0.0")
            case arr => arr
          }
        }
        acc :+ (k.trim.toInt, v.trim.toDouble)
    }
}
```